# Bounce rate in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have website in which when a user land on the website(say xyz.com) . Website open with a pop up(no tracking is enable on the popup) and user cannot perform any action unless it closes the pop up and also the page is not reloaded after closing the pop up

below are my queries. 
1) No tracking enable on pop up close 
 If user doesn't visit any more pages in the website post closing the pop up. But perform different action on same page (such as check box selection ,drop down selection) on which event are define. do still this page will be calculated as bounce page and visit will be calculated as bounce visit?

2)  Tracking enable on pop up close .
 If user doesn't visit any more pages in the website post closing the pop up. But perform different action on same page(such as check box selection ,drop down selection) on which event are define. do still this page will be calculated as bounce page and visit will be calculated as bounce visit?

3) Tracking enable on pop up close 
Post closing pop up user doesn't perform any activity.
do still this page will be calculated as bounce page and visit will be calculated as bounce visit?

Answer (score 0):

A bounce is a visit with only one interaction.

If both your site and the popup have tracking code that's two interactions and the visitor will not be counted as a bounce.

In the case of events it depends. You can [set a flag in your event tracking code](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide?hl=en) that determines if the event affects the bounce rate. By default an event will count as interaction, and a user with a pageview and an event will not count as bounce. However if you set the "noninteraction" flag to "true" the event will not be counted towards the bounce rate (i.e. somebody who has only one pageview and one or multiple event hit will still count as a bounce).

So for your examples, and any other use cases you can come up with, simply count the numbers of interactions that do not have a non-interaction flag set (and adjust your tracking code according to your use case). If the number is larger than 0 the visit will not be counted as a bounce.

Comment: Hi Eike thanks for the reply.   But I am not able get your below point .     By default an event will count as interaction, and a user with a pageview and an event will not count as bounce. However if you set the "noninteraction" flag to "true" the event will not be counted towards the bounce rate (i.e. somebody who has only one pageview and one or multiple event hit will still count as a bounce ) .As per my understanding you are suggesting that if a set  noninteraction" flag to "true". Then a visit with a single page and one or more event hit will be count towards bounce ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. if the noninteraction flag is set to true a single pageview + events will be treated like just a pageview. I.e. this will be counted as a single interaction and thus as a bounce.

Comment: Thnx Eike for the  knowledge you shared . It really helped me implementing my Tag's .One more query  . If following is the scenario                 step 1) Visitor visit home page  step 2) On home page user click on dropdown on which event is define but  (""noninteraction" flag to "true")  Step 3) On home page after click on dropdown event user click on check box on which event is define but  (noninteraction" flag to "false"). In this scenario will this be consider as bounce visit and home page will consider as bounce page.